# Replace double quote value based on key present in json object

Tags: javascript

I am evaluating if I can achieve the following use case in Javascript, because I want to use this inline script in Logicapp

Input Text:

```
{"id":2097,"date":"2021-12-03T00:00:22","name":"data-load","cData":"This game is the most played game inside "USA". If you are also sure of your luck, then you must take this ticket. If you have "good luck", then the next first prize can be "yours"."}
```

Expected Output Json

```
{"id":2097,"date":"2021-12-03T00:00:22","name":"data-load","cData":"This game is the most played game inside \"USA\". If you are also sure of your luck, then you must take this ticket. If you have \"good luck\", then the next first prize can be \"yours\"."}
```

Need the value change for Key ["cData"] only. It should be very simple, I think.

I am not familiar with JavaScript though want to explore the options here as well so I can save some extra loop in LogicApp.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: where is this input coming from? It is not valid JSON or valid javascript in general. To 'fix' this isn't so trivial and would involve regular expressions and anyways, it's best to find out why it's being supplied this way and fix that IMHO.

Comment: This is not a simple task due to the fact that you only want to replace what's in `cData`, and you can't convert it to an object because it's an invalid JSON. You could technically write a regular expression to do it, but that begs the question, why are you passing an invalid JSON to begin with?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I totally agree with you, it's not a valid json but source team is generating the txt file like this only and I have to take care it. any suggestion how to do it in javascript, if it possible?